# Scroll jumpy inside overflow DIV only on windows machine with touch

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm having an issue where the scroll inside a div on a windows machine is a bit jumpy.

There's some scripting involved where the adjacent div scrolls the opposite direction.  Can someone take a look and see what's causing the jumpiness?

http://dev-pavlov-agency.pantheonsite.io/portfolio/

This is the attached script, which works great elsewhere:

function rightscroll(){

```
  var scrolltopper = $("#work-archive .box-1-2.right .scroll-inner").height();
  $("#work-archive .box-1-2.right").scrollTop(scrolltopper );

  var scrolledright = parseInt($("#work-archive .box-1-2.right").scrollTop());

    $("#work-archive .box-1-2.left").on("scroll", function () {
        var scrolledleft = parseInt($("#work-archive .box-1-2.left").scrollTop()) * -1;
        $("#work-archive .box-1-2.right").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
        console.log(scrolledleft + scrolledright);
    });

    $("#work-archive .box-1-2.right").on("scroll", function () {
        var scrolledleft = parseInt($("#work-archive .box-1-2.right").scrollTop()) * -1;
        $("#work-archive .box-1-2.left").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
        console.log(scrolledleft + scrolledright);
    });      


};

setTimeout(rightscroll, 1000);
```

Comment: I found the reason why this is occuring.  On windows machines, the second 'on.scroll' function is triggered by scrolltop in the first function.  Now that I know the cause, any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: added two variables that limited the functions depending on which div was being scrolled in, works great now.